# Async/Await function without a return | Swift 5.5

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I remove the Bool return from my function without getting the error:

```
Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

This is the function:

```
private func syncDataStore() async throws -> Bool {
    try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        Amplify.DataStore.stop { (result) in
            switch(result) {
            case .success:
                Amplify.DataStore.start { (result) in
                    switch(result) {
                    case .success:
                        print("DataStore started")
                        continuation.resume(returning: true)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("Error starting DataStore:\(error)")
                        continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error stopping DataStore:\(error)")
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I tried to do but I get the error mentioned above:

```
private func syncDataStore() async throws {
    try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        Amplify.DataStore.stop { (result) in
            switch(result) {
            case .success:
                Amplify.DataStore.start { (result) in
                    switch(result) {
                    case .success:
                        print("DataStore started")
                        continuation.resume()
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("Error starting DataStore:\(error)")
                        continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error stopping DataStore:\(error)")
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Honestly I don't know why it's complaining, no returns are there and it's not tie to any model or anything...

Comment: What happens if you specify the type of `continuation` explicitly? `(continuation: UnsafeContinuation<Bool, Error>) in` I would expect the error to change to something more useful, or better, go away entirely.

Comment: @Sweeper it went away like this:  `(continuation: UnsafeContinuation<Void, Error>) in` however it looks too long, isn't there a better way?

Comment: I think the root cause is that the statements you are putting inside the closure is too complicated, and the type inference just gives up. You can try wrapping `stop` and `start` into async functions separately, then writing an async function for `syncDataStore` would be trivial.

Comment: Actually, async functions that return `Void` should be possible. Try changing it to `-> Void`.

Comment: @Sweeper that didn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what worked the best:

```
try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { (continuation: UnsafeContinuation<Void, Error>) in
```

Answer (score 9):

The trick is to cast return value of `withUnsafeThrowingContinuation` to `Void`, like so:

```swift
try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in
    someAsyncFunction() { error in
        if let error = error { continuation.resume(throwing: error) }
        else { continuation.resume() }
    }
} as Void
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at signature

```
/// Suspends the current task,
/// then calls the given closure with the an unsafe throwing continuation for the current task.
///
/// - Parameter fn: A closure that takes an `UnsafeContinuation` parameter.
/// You must resume the continuation exactly once.
///
/// - Returns: The value passed to the continuation by the closure.
///
/// If `resume(throwing:)` is called on the continuation,
/// this function throws that error.
@available(macOS 12.0, iOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, tvOS 15.0, *)
public func withUnsafeThrowingContinuation<T>(_ fn: (UnsafeContinuation<T, Error>) -> Void) async throws -> T
```

as it is seen `withUnsafeThrowingContinuation` is function with generics on return value which type is detected from continuation

So the solution for your case can be as follows:

```
private func syncDataStore() async throws {
    _ = try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation { continuation in

        // ...

        continuation.resume(returning: true)

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: actually that still delivers the same error message: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
`

Comment: Then it is in code that I cannot replicate. The provided code snapshot, as tested, is compilable with Xcode 13 / iOS 15.

Comment: This code is actually returning a `Bool`, look at the `returning: true`. It works, but it doesn't answer the question of how to return `Void`.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your "private func syncDataStore() async throws {...}":

```
return try await withUnsafeThrowingContinuation {....}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private func syncDataStore() async throws -> Void {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        ...
        case .success:
            continuation.resume()
        case .failure(let error):
            continuation.resume(throwing: error)
        ...
    }
}
```

This does work on iOS 14

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).